# return value meaning | pattern

Tags: c, recursion

What does the following function return? (in terms of meaning)

```
int f(int n){
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    else return n % 2 + f(n / 2)
}
```

Tried running the code, but couldn’t find any pattern in the results

Comment: What do you get for the first few values of n (e.g. 0 to 9) ?

Comment: 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2

Comment: Hint: try writing out each value of n in *binary* - the pattern should then be obvious, and you will probably also begin to understand how the code works,

Comment: done this, not obvious to me at all :/

Comment: Count the number of 1 bits in each input value...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This output of this function can be interpreted as the number of 1s (in base 10) when the number `n` is represented in binary.

The base case is when `n == 0`, where the number of 1s is `0`.

For every other `n`, there is a recursive call. There are two parts to this. The first, which is `n % 2`, finds out the last bit of `n`. If it is a `1`, it contributes to the value returned, and is hence, counted. The second part, `f(n/2)`, is computing the number of 1s in all the bits of `n` except the last bit. This is because `n/2` is `n` with a one bit right shift.

To put it together, the function works as follows. It checks the last bit, and if `1`, it adds it to the total. It then performs a recursive call on itself with the last bit removed. This goes on till all bits are removed, which is covered by the base case.